# Omit the redirection responses on the html report results when running performance tests using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm running performance tests against a server, which uses a proxy that redirects (302) to the real backend service (api under test).

[image]

As result of that, when running the tests I get always two responses per requests (302 and 200) which is totally fine, but I wouldn't like it to be displayed in the html report that i generate using JMeter CLI:

```
jmeter -n -t Workbench_Performance_Test_Plan.jmx -l LoadTest/loadtest.csv -e -o LoadTest/HtmlReport -f
```

So these are displayed as `get link by id-0` and `get link by id-1`

[image]

I've seen there is a way to filter by success or error in the View Results Tree or Table, but is there a way to omit those additional requests (302) using any kind of filtering without removing the errors?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I post my solution here in case anybody runs into the same issue.

In the Http Request Sampler there is a checkbox to force "Redirect Automatically" that has to be checked:

[image]

So in this way the published results (as well as the View Result tree output)  will display only one row or item per request:

[image]